# How do I get grub menu to boot after reboot of antix22 net iso cli-install in qemu/kvm with virt manager?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I am trying to install Antix22-net-iso with cli-installer in a VM using Qemu/kvm virt-manager. Everything goes well until I am asked to remove the installation CD then reboot. after entering "reboot" the installer again asks to remove the CD and close the tray then press enter to reboot. When I do this it reboots to the screen in the below screenshot. The VM does not reboot and I can't do anything else.

I was following a video on YouTube by Dolphin Oracle showing how to install the same is in a virtual machine, but when I reboot it will not boot to grub! What do I need to do so I come to the grub menu after reboot? This is a net install, so I still have to continue with installing a desktop and other applications like you would get in a full ISO install.

Screen at reboot:

[image: screen at reboot]

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using? Antix is not an official flavor of Ubuntu and is off topic here.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 22.04 xfce DE. Antix is just the linux ditribution I am trying to install on the  VM

Comment: But your problem is exactly with the distro you're trying to install, not with the host OS Ubuntu. Your question is then off-topic here. You can post at Unix & Linux but a better, more accurate, description of the problem is strongly recommended.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: Simply configure that VM to have a CD-ROM and boot grml from it and fix your issue from there.  In the distant past, unix single-user-mode was just booting the kernel an running a shell on the console without running any startup scripts or similar. You had 
(very nearly) total control over what would happen when the system booted. Eventually Sun Microsystems lost their mind and decided that single-user-mode meant starting practically everything, so you had to boot from a CD or DVD to fix things. Then Linux developers drank that kool-aide too and now that is what Ubuntu is.